# Can't access drive

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my D: drive with partitions. But, when I try to access the drive from windows, it shows invalid. After looking at the disk status, it has been converted to a dynamic drive. I am only able to access the information through Ubuntu.

Is there a solution for this problem or I just need to back up my data, convert the drive into a basic one, and install Ubuntu again!

Comment: You haven't said what release or version of Windows. The standard versions of Windows can only read native file-systems, unless you've added support for non-native file-systems (you didn't say if you formatted your windows using ext4, btrfs, reiserfs or another file-system though default is usually ext4). It reads to me like you've a home/consumer grade (professional etc) release that cannot read the non-native *fs* used by Ubuntu, or the non-native has been disabled (if enterprise/server grade windows)

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not play well with other (non-M$) file systems.  It probably can't read your EXT4 file system.

Comment: How to solve such an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Windows cannot read an `ext4` drive. One possible solution would be to backup your D: drive, and then format it as `NTFS` using GPartEd.

Then both Ubuntu and Windows would be able to access it.

Comment: Can I just format it using windows disk manager?

Comment: Yes, you can. Ubuntu must have a partition of its own but it can read and write to NTFS file partitions natively.

Comment: I think Ubuntu will also need a swap partition.  So, when you format with disk manager, be careful not to wipe out that swap partition, which should have been created during the Ubuntu installation. You also should not change the filesystem type on the swap partition.  Leave it as Ubuntu created it.